# Question about Dynamic Scoping example output

Tags: programming-languages, semantics

I'm trying to do a runtime stack on a simple code example that uses dynamic scoping. The code is this:

```
void g() {
  int r = 10;
  c = 2;
  b = a;
}

void f() {
  int b;
  b = a;
  a = a + 1;

  g();

  print a, b, c;
}

void main() {
  int a, b, c;
  a = 2;
  b = 4;
  c = 6;

  f();

  print a, b, c; 
}
```

For the first print, I'm getting `3 3 2`, which is correct. However, for the second print (in main) I'm getting `3 3 2` when the correct answer is `3 4 2`.

I got `3 3 2` because the value of `a` is assigned to `b` which is `3` in function `g()`, which is called by `f()`. I don't see `b` being changed after that.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: This programming question is off-topic here.

Comment: To me it seems like dynamic scope question with C-*ish* pseudocode, so it is ontopic.

Comment: Ok. To make it hint (at least for now), do you assume that variable $b$ in main is the same one that in function $f$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Yes, I did.  Once you stated that, I noticed the "int b;" in function f(), that I didn't note before. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: This question only makes sense if you define the scoping rules. Is "dynamic scoping" specific enough?

Comment: @Raphael "dynamic scoping" is perfectly specific and very simple rule. "Bring your own environment variables to the stack" ;). But I do not know what to do now? How shoud answer look? More general defining this concept? Author shoud self-answer or what?